# Potenciação com array

Tags: c#, .net, matemática

Pensei no seguinte código para calcular o quadrado de cada valor na *array*:

```
double []vetor =  {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10};
        double result = 0;
          foreach(double posicao in vetor){
              result = Math.Pow(posicao, 2);
              vetor[result] = result;
          }  
          Console.WriteLine($"{String.Join(" , ", vetor)}.");
```

Aparece esse erro:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `double' to` int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: O problema do seu código está em: vetor[result], o indexador de array espera um inteiro, mas você está acessando com um double.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa fazer essa gambiarra, deixa inteiro e faça sem usar função auxiliar (entendi que só uso `double` para usar a função). Mas não pode usar `foreach` quando vai alterar o elemento da coleção tem que usar o `for` normal, então seria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main()   {
        int []vetor =  { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10 };
        for (int i = 0; i < vetor.Length; i++ ) vetor[i] *= vetor[i];
        WriteLine($"{string.Join(", ", vetor)}.");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/REUaUQ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MBNXTj). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/MultiplyElements.cs).